# Unnest object with array values

Tags: javascript

Here's my input object —

```json
{
    "email": [
      "abc"
    ],
    "name": [
      "def",
      "ghi"
    ],
    "number": [
      "123",
      "456"
    ]
}
```

Here's what I'm hoping to get as output —

```json
[
  {
    "email":"abc",
    "name":"def",
    "number":"123"
  },
  {
    "email":"abc",
    "name":"ghi",
    "number":"123"
  },
  {
    "email":"abc",
    "name":"def",
    "number":"456"
  },
  {
    "email":"abc",
    "name":"ghi",
    "number":"456"
  }
]
```

And, here's my code —

```js
const input = {
  "email": [
    "abc"
  ],
  "name": [
    "def",
    "ghi"
  ],
  "number": [
    "123",
    "456"
  ]
};

const keys = Object.keys(input);

const values = Object.values(input);
let depth = [];
let output = [];
values.forEach(value => depth.push(value.length));
depth = depth.reduce((a, b)=> a*b, 1);
let dict = {};
for (let i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
    let key = keys[j];
    if (input[key][i] !== undefined) {
      dict[key] = input[key][i];
    }
  }
  console.log(dict);
  output.push(dict);
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry  updated the thread.

Comment: There's no [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) in your question. `input` is just an object: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: Don't use the `json` tag for this. See its usage description.

Comment: Sorry sorry, again  removed the `json` tag

Comment: You want the cartesian product of the array in all properties.

Comment: So you have three arrays and you want to perform the cartesian product. You can check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks all for the comments — sorry for not already knowing these but it has been an amazing learning process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach by calculating the product of the lengths is certainly one that can work. But there are some problems with the implementation that make it fail:

- With `let dict = {};` you only create *one* object, and that object is being pushed to the result array repeatedly. Any mutation to that object will thus be seen in very entry of that result array. So you should at least create that `dict` object in every iteration of the outer loop
- `i` will in many cases exceed the length of the `input[key]` array, so `input[key][i]` will be undefined. Yet you need to pick a value from that array. You should use modular logic to translate such `i` to a valid index, and then use the *remainder* of that `i` in the next iteration of the inner loop -- to pick a value from the next array.

Here is a slight adaptation of your code to tackle those issues. I also moved it into a function:

```js
function cartesian(input) {
    let keys = Object.keys(input);
    let depth = Object.values(input).reduce((product, {length}) => product * length, 1);
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
        let j = i;
        let dict = {};
        for (let key of keys) {
            let size = input[key].length;
            dict[key] = input[key][j % size];
            j = Math.floor(j / size);
        }
        result.push(dict);
    }
    return result;
}

const input = {
  "email": [
    "abc"
  ],
  "name": [
    "def",
    "ghi"
  ],
  "number": [
    "123",
    "456"
  ]
};

let result = cartesian(input);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the answers provided on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript).

### Step 1

Extract the three arrays:

```
const {email, name, number} = input;
```

### Step 2

Perform the cartesian product:

```
const cartesian = (...a) => a.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(d => b.map(e => [d, e].flat())));
const product = cartesian(email, name, number);
```

### Step 3

Recompose the output:

```
const output = product.map(triple => ({email: triple[0], name: triple[1], number: triple[2]}));
```

You can replace the `cartesian` function with other functions found in the related question, accordingly to the target version of ES you mean to support.

@pilchard proposes a more generic version, which doesn't need you to specify the properties, but just performs the cartesian product on all the ones available within an object, and it is:

```
const result = cartesian(...Object.entries(input).map(([k, vs]) => vs.map(v => [[k, v]]))).map(Object.fromEntries)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but I guess the reason is obvious. Vote to close as a duplicate and don't copy and paste another answer. Multiple copies of the same answer aren't useful.

Comment: It's an extension to the other answers. The other question is about cartesian product on arrays, here we talk about object properties. Chance are that if I just closed the question as a duplicate the OP was left confused and wouldn't know how to apply the information

Comment: It also proposes a hardcoded solution based on preset properties rather than a more generic solution which would be simple enough. But mostly it's a duplicate, though I agree that implementation of the duplicate is confusing enough to warrant an answer here.

Comment: Closing a question as a duplicate should happen when the questions are exactly the same, that means when the answers of a question can be transferred to the other question. This is not the case

Comment: generic solution: `const result = cartesian(...Object.entries(input).map(([k, vs]) => vs.map(v => [[k, v]]))).map(Object.fromEntries);` [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yga3ohsk/1/)

Comment: @plichard you can add it as answer and I'd upvote it. My answer does what OP asked, a more generic version is appreciated for sure

Comment: Feel free to add it to your answer, I think one reference to the cartesian product answer is enough.